# Error while simulating the speed control of a brushed DC motor using a 555 timer and a high boost convertor using Multisim simulator

Tags: 555, motor-controller, brushed-dc-motor

Reference paper: https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/6183251

I'm trying to simulate the speed control for a brushed DC motor using a 555 timer (astable multivibrator) and a high boost convertor using the multisim software.
[image: Simulation]

It simulates for a while before giving me a simulation error. Any tips on how I can fix this would be highly appreciated.

Comment: the error message dialog gives you an option to follow

Comment: Can't see the article, but your circuit is really weird, a total nonsense.

Comment: Please, do not provide link to a paper, that nobody will click. And even then - one would have to sign in on the site to see it. Paste a circuit from the paper as an image.